# NgFor display data in table with user input number of columns

Tags: angular

I have a component that accepts an array input lets say [1,2,3,4,5,6,7] and number of Columns input .

If user enters 3 columns then on UI I want to display data in a 3 column table as below .

1 2 3
4 5 6
7

If user enters 4 then data will be displayed as below

1  2  3  4 
5  6  7

Is it possible to generate table with dynamic number of columns from the array by just using *ngfor without typescript code.

Comment: Post what you've tried

Comment: nest two `*ngfors` should do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, is possible but it's not effective

```
<div *ngFor="let rows of '1'.repeat(array.length).split('')
           .slice(0,1+array.length/count);let i=index">
   <span *ngFor="let element of array.slice(i*count,(i+1)*count)">
     {{element}}
   </span>
</div>
```

It's better create a function

```
  groupArray(array: any[], count: number) {
    const result: any = [];
    array.forEach((x, index) => {
      if (index % count == 0) 
          result.push([]);

      result[result.length - 1].push(x);
    });
    return result;
  }
```

You can use like

```
this.groupArray([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],4)
```

Then iterate using two *ngFor

```
<div *ngFor="let group of groupArray">
 <span*ngFor="let element of group">
   {{element}}
 </span>
</div>
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-k1s3qk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)
(Updated stackblitz)

Comment: Problem with function is if array length is changed or the number columns entered by user is changed then UI does not reflect changes .