# Table viem for *ngFor in angular

Tags: html, css, angular

I have an array with a known size like 100. I do *ngFor and get 100 elements in a row.  But I need to present them in the form of a table, for example 10x10.  How can I make it beautiful?  You can probably choose a certain width: % to fit 10 elements in a row, but I want to find a normal solution.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59382934/ngfor-display-data-in-table-with-user-input-number-of-columns/59387996#59387996

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about the [best way to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to provide a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).